# MVC Html.EditorFor wont accept markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Guys,
One of my textboxes needs to accept a user inputting HTML:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Setting, new { model = Model })%>
```

When I put plain text into the box it correctly populates my Setting property.

When I put the following into the textbox I get nothing:

```
<b>Text<b>
```

Just a clue as to how to even debug this would be appreciated.  Many thanks.

Comment: Is the problem that you are unable to postback with the textbox when it contains HTML (this is normal), or that the rendered output is blank when the model contains HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting `[ValidateInput(false)]` on top of your action?
I bet it's sth related to input validation and the fact that you're posting HTML markup.